# Complexity of division

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory, division, asymptotic-complexity

The article [Computational complexity of mathematical operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations) mentions that the complexity of division in `O(M(n))`, and that "`M(n)` below stands in for the complexity of the chosen multiplication algorithm".

But I'm not sure how to read that `M(n)` embedded in `O(M(n))`: does it mean that the division has the same complexity as multiplication?

If I use, say, Karatsuba multiplication algorithm, will the division also take `O(n^1.585)`?

Answer (score 0):

> does it mean that the division has the same complexity as multiplication?

Formally, it means division cannot have a complexity worse than multiplication. But in practice, the notation is often use to say they have the same complexity.

> If I use, say, Karatsuba multiplication algorithm, will the division also take `O(n^1.585)`?

According to the statement, yes.

However, I am not sure that statement is correct. Indeed, when looking at the Newton–Raphson method, I see it is an iterative process, which has to be repeated a certain number of times to be exact, in the order of `log(n)` (see the discussion about `S` [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%E2%80%93Raphson_division#Newton.E2.80.93Raphson_division)).
In that case, the complexity would be `O(log(n)M(n))`.

However, if it is not a problem for you to have only a fixed precision (ie. the number of correct digits) whatever the size of the operands are, you can set a constant number of iterations, resulting in a `O(M(n))` complexity.

Comment: The original statement is correct. The flaw in your argument follows from the fact that you can do N-R iterations gradually increasing precision, thus instead of log(n)*M(n) you get `M(1)+M(2)+M(4)+...+ M(2^log(n))`.

Comment: Indeed, I haven't thought of that